# Policy for REST API but not for Controllers in sails.js

Tags: rest, sails.js

Assume the following situation:

Policies:

- `userNotLoggedIn`

  - makes sure there's no authenticated user yet
- `userIsAdministrator`

  - makes sure the user is authenticated ***and*** is an administrator

Model:

- `User`

  - personal data as well as the encrypted password

Controller:

- `UserController`

  - including a `login` function that uses `User.findOne`

I want to restrict the access to `UserController.login` to the policy `userIsNotLoggedIn` and restrict the access to the REST API of `User` to the policy `userIsAdministrator`.

If I set the policy of `UserController.login` to `userNotLoggedIn`, not authorized users **cannot** access the REST API for `User` which is good and as expected. And they can also perform a login. But if you're logged in you still can't access the REST API (which makes sense, since I haven't declared a policy for it yet).

```
// config/policies.js
'UserController': {
    'login': 'userNotLoggedIn'
}
```

Now I want to open up the REST  API for the `userIsAdministrator` policy by restricting `User.*` to `userIsAdministrator` in `policies.js`, but now you can't perform `UserController.login` since it uses `User.findOne` which is restricted to `userIsAdministrator`. **This is bad.**

```
// config/policies.js
'UserController': {
    'login': 'userNotLoggedIn'
},

'User': {
    '*': 'userIsAdministrator'
}
```

If I then open `User.findOne` to `userIsNotLoggedIn`, the login performs as expected, but this opens up the REST API as well, so anyone can query the user database without being logged in.

```
// config/policies.js
'UserController': {
    'login': 'userNotLoggedIn'
},

'User': {
    '*': 'userIsAdministrator',
    'findOne': 'userIsNotLoggedIn'
}
```

**Is it possible to restrict the access of `User.*` to `userIsAdministrator` for the REST API only, while keeping it open for the controllers so `UserController.login` is still able to look up the user and log in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a policy to a Blueprint Action you have to specify it on the controller not on the model:

```
// config/policies.js
'UserController': {
    '*': 'userIsAdministrator',
    'login': 'userNotLoggedIn'
}
```

Blueprint Action Routes like all RESTful routes *map* to the corresponding Blueprint Action of the controller.

Translation of the "policy" above:

- Apply `userIsAdministrator` to **all** methods of `UserController` (this also prevents RESTful routes from being run) except the following further declared policies
- Apply `userNotLoggedIn` to `UserController.login`

So setting this in combination with a global `'*': false` should keep all data secret.

Comment: Fabio, what if I needed to restrict some Blueprint Action to some role, but leave others open to others? For example, if I want `POST /model/` to be  `userIsAdmin` but `GET /model/<id>` to be `userIsLoggedIn`? I didn't find a way to specify HTTP method in the policies.